# Loading NetBSD kernel modules

Tags: kernel-modules, netbsd

I want to start using `npf` on my NetBSD server, rather than relying solely on the external firewall for protection.  However, I get:

```
$ npfctl show
npfctl: /dev/npf: No such file or directory
```

Alright, maybe I deleted a device node.  No matter:

```
$ grep npf /dev/MAKEDEV
        makedev bpf npf
npf)
        mkdev npf        c 198 0
# mknod /dev/npf c 198 0
$ npfctl show
npfctl: /dev/npf: Device not configured
```

Oh, right, have to load the driver first:

```
$ modstat | grep npf; echo $?
1
$ find /stand -name 'npf.kmod'
/stand/sparc64/7.0/modules/npf/npf.kmod
$ uname -sr
NetBSD 7.0.2
# modload npf
modload: Operation not permitted
```

Why am I (even as root) not permitted to load modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBSD uses [kernel secure levels](https://wiki.netbsd.org/kernel_secure_levels/) to determine what operations can be performed on a running system.  From the link:

> ## -1 Permanently insecure mode
>
> - Don't raise the securelevel on boot
>
> ## 0 Insecure mode
>
> - The `init` process (PID 1) may not be traced or accessed by `ptrace(2)`, `systrace(4)`, or `procfs`.
> - Immutable and append-only file flags may be changed
> - All devices may be read or written subject to their permissions
>
> Note: You can't run X11 above this securelevel
>
> Try `sysutils/aperture` if you really need it.
>
> ## 1 Secure mode
>
> - All effects of securelevel 0
> - `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` may not be written to
> - Raw disk devices of mounted file systems are read-only
> - Immutable and append-only file flags may not be removed
> - Kernel modules may not be loaded or unloaded
> - The net.inet.ip.sourceroute `sysctl(8)` variable may not be changed
> - Adding or removing `sysctl(9)` nodes is denied
> - The RTC offset may not be changed
> - Set-id coredump settings may not be altered
> - Attaching the IP-based kernel debugger, `ipkdb(4)`, is not allowed
> - Device pass-thru requests that may be used to perform raw disk and/or memory access are denied
> - `iopl` and `ioperm` calls are denied
> - Access to unmanaged memory is denied
>
> ## 2 Highly secure mode
>
> - All effects of securelevel 1
> - Raw disk devices are always read-only whether mounted or not
> - New disks may not be mounted, and existing mounts may only be downgraded from read-write to read-only
> - The system clock may not be set backwards or close to overflow
> - Per-process coredump name may not be changed
> - Packet filtering and NAT rules may not be altered

My system was running at securelevel 1, so "Kernel modules may not be loaded or unloaded".  Further, setting `npf=YES` in `rc.conf` does not automatically load the associated kernel module.  One cannot lower the kernel secure level at runtime, so the options are:

- Boot to a lower securelevel, then load the module and raise the securelevel, or
- Load the module during boot

Clearly the latter is the better option.  To load a kernel module at boot, one must ensure that `rc.conf` contains:

```
modules=YES
```

Then, edit (or create) `/etc/modules.conf` to contain a list of modules to load, one per line.  In this case:

```
# echo npf >> /etc/modules.conf
```